# HTML/JavaScript - How can I hide the links and cursor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a JavaScript/HTML template for my website however I am having trouble trying to figure out how to hide links and cursors when at different ID's.

The URL's end like so http://domain.com/index.html#about etc. The homepage Which is the following code:

```
<!-- Home Page -->
    <section class="content show" id="home">
        <h1>THIS IS THE HEADER</h1>
        <h5>SUB HEADING</h5>
        <p>THIS IS A PARAGRAPH OF TEXT.</p>

    </section>
```

is the content that initially shows, the rest use "content hide". The issue I am having is that when at other ID's eg #services even though the content from other pages is hidden, links and cursors can still display when navigating the page. An example would be my templates page:

```
             <!-- Web Templates -->
    <section class="content hide" id="web_templates">
        <h2>HTML Stand Alone Website Templates</h2>
        <h3>Free Templates</h3>
        <!--THE IMAGES ARE PLACED IN AN UNORDERED LIST-->
        <ul class="enlarge"> <!--We give the list a class so that we can style it seperately from other unordered lists-->
        <!--First Image-->
        <li>
        <img src="images/free_web_templates/hairstylesalon.jpg" width="150px" height="100px" alt="Hair Style Salon" /> <!--thumbnail image-->
        <span> <!--span contains the popup image-->
        <img src="images/free_web_templates/hairstylesalon.jpg" alt="Hair Style Salon" /> <!--popup image-->
        <br />Hair Style Salon (Free Website Templates) <a href="#">Download</a> <!--caption appears under the popup image-->
        </span>
        </li>
        </ul>

    </section>
```

When not on this page the hand cursor displays on every page even though the content is hidden. Is there anyway I can fix this so that when at different ID's in the URL the content including cursors and links is hidden?

The CSS for content:

```
.content { 
float:left;
margin:40px;
position:absolute;
top:200px;
width:600px;
z-index:9999;
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
```

}

The Main JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

/* How to Handle Hashtags */
jQuery(window).hashchange(function(){
    var hash = location.hash;
    jQuery('a[href='+hash+']').trigger('click');
});

/* Main Navigation Clicks */
jQuery('.main-nav ul li a').click(function() {
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(1);

    if ( !jQuery('section.content.show, section#' + link).is(':animated') ) {
        jQuery('.main-nav ul li a').removeClass('active'); //remove active
        jQuery('section.content.show').addClass('show').animate({'opacity' : 0}, {queue: false, duration: 1000,
            complete: function() {
                jQuery('a[href="#'+link+'"]').addClass('active'); // add active
                jQuery('section#' + link).addClass('show').animate({'opacity' : 1}, {queue: false, duration: 1000});    
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: no offense.....but please rephrase and show only the relevant part of code....its to bulky to read!!

Comment: What's the CSS behind `content hide`? It should be `display:none;` if you do not want it to be in the page.

Comment: I edited it to make it clearer and added the content CSS and main nav JS

Comment: while it's probably better to hide the content you don't want seen, are you familiar with css cursors? http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for

`{display:none}` which makes things invisible and the space the element occupies is collapsed?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. I have the content CSS which sets the page elements then in the HTML I told it to hide. I'll give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: From your snippet above, you're setting opacity to 0, but the element's still there on the page. Setting `display` to `none` removes the element from being interacted with at all. Does that make sense? Alternatively, you might be interested in jQuery's effect and show / hide methods:  http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/